# My Prefix is an abbreviation of the whole word, My Infix is a place used to keep criminals,

Tags: riddle, word

My Prefix is an abbreviation of the whole word

My Infix is a place used to keep criminals

My Suffix, though consists of only 2 letters, is another word for ourselves

What is the word?

Comment: Comments and suggestions are welcome as this is my first post. Will add hints if it is  too hard.

Comment: Usually there is a hint for the whole word as well to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: Noted @wolfram42

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> Miscellaneous

My Prefix is an abbreviation of the whole word

> Often abbreviated Misc.

My Infix is a place used to keep criminals

> Cells are used to keep criminals.

My Suffix, though consists of only 2 letters, is another word for ourselves

> Us

Comment: Correct! May I ask whether this is too easy?

Comment: It's relatively easy, but not too easy. The suffix clue was obvious and there are only a few things the infix could be. Perhaps you could make the clues a little more cryptic in the future, and add a clue for the whole word as wolfram42 suggested.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion @Riley

Answer (score 3):

Probably wrong, but to get the ball rolling

> Calculus

Because:

> It is abbreviated as Cal, Cul (short for cul de sac) is a dead end. And "us" is 2 letters for "ourselves"

Comment: Nice try but not the correct word. +1 for fitting all the requirements.

Comment: @KevinL Fitting all the requirements? Where is the place used to keep criminals?